# What MySQL data type should be used for xsd:anyURI?

Tags: mysql, database, xsd

I have a parameter that i wish to store into my MySQL database.

Here is the description of the parameter :

**Parameter Name** : endUserId

**Type** : xsd:anyURI

**Max Length** : 256

**Description** : The format is 'tel:' followed by '+' and followed by the phone number
for e.g. tel: +22507588125 , The endUserId in the URL must be the same and URL-escaped, i.e. tel%3A%2B22507588125

so what data type is suitable for the parameter 'endUserId' described above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maximum length of 256 is larger than required. I have never seen a phone number with more than, say, 15 digits. Under reasonable constraints, you could store the phone number as a `BIGINT`. Just store the numeric part, and format the output (append "tel:+") when only you read it.

You may also store the international prefix apart, i.e. a phone number would be stored in two numeric columns (one for the international prefix, another for the actual phone number -- I am told no phone number has a `0` after its international prefix).

If the max size of 256 is not negociable, then your only choice is `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Looks like a URI in the `tel` scheme to me.  (But I have no answers to your other questions.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Brain fart, I suppose. Thanks for the pointer!